# Google AppEngine app.yaml error 500

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml, handler

I'm having problems getting my assets folder to upload to the root, but also allowing a custom url handler `/cron` to upload too.

```
application: appname
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /cron
  script: assets/backup/main.py

- url: /
  static_files: assets/index.html
  upload: assets/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: assets
```

As you can see, my backup script is also located in my assets or *static* folder. If I remove my `static_dir: assets` handler, my `/cron` handler works fine.

I also tried changing the `url` to `/assets` to see if I could overwrite it that way.

Any idea why this happens and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the whole assets directory as static with `static_dir: assets`. You can't run any script inside a static_dir. The fix is to move `assets/backup/main.py` to outside the directory defined as static_dir.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you moraes. It all makes sense, a script isn't static content!